# Why Firefox crashes using Google

Tags: firefox, crash, gmail, google-search

My Firefox always crashes when using Google (search / mail). Tried uninstalling plugins, deleting and installing Firefox again but nothing helps. Any ideas?

Comment: Any sort of error log you can give us?

Comment: Do any problems occur when using IE, Chrome, etc? Honestly I got tired of Firefox crashing on me randomly too so I switched to chrome. What version of FF?

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by "crash."

Comment: Have you tried clearing the FF cache (so files google assumed are the right versions get reloaded).

Comment: Stumbled across this old question that's still showing as unsolved.  By now, it's surely either been solved or overtaken by events.  Can you update this?  If you solved it, maybe add an answer with what the solution was?  If the issue just became moot without a resolution, maybe add a note in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Firefox in safe mode? If that still causes a crash, it's time to reinstall Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall Firefox after that clear \AppData\Roaming\Mozilla before uninstall you can take Crash Reports.

If you want show appdata folder. You can go to start, next write %appdata% and you will see AppData folder.

After clean AppData...\Mozilla and uninstall, you can download ccleaner and using this program to clean you registry. After that please reboot your computer now install Firefox.

If still will be problem witch Firefox, you can try install it in different path than default for example on D:\